# Mobile Vison API detect no QR code

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code, android-vision

I'm developing a QR code scanner with Mobile Vision API (play-services-vision 11.0.1). I've run my application on two Android devices (Xperia SO-04E Android 4.2.2). My application works correctly on one device but does not detect QR code on the other. Camera started correctly, but detected no QR code. Does anyone know a solution? Might does a device's configuration cause this?

A part of source code(Activity written in Kotlin) is as below. I've configured the camera permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
// instantiate barcode detector in an Activity onCreate method
val barcodeDetector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).build()
cameraSource = CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
               .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
               .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)

 // set callback
 barcodeDetector.setProcessor(object: Detector.Processor<Barcode>?) {
     override fun release() {}

     override fun receiveDetections(detections: Detector.Detections<Barcode>?) {
         ・・・
         // parse a detected QR code
         ・・・
     }

 }
```

Comment: Please check the google play services version on device.

Answer (score 0):

Check internet connection on the second device; As Vision API requires Google play services and this needs internet connection; however need not to provide permission in Manifest file..